# How to direct output into file in Python to allow sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

After being given the solution on how to extract the needed info from a JSON file, I now need to direct that output into a new file. The code for extracting is:

```
for result in developer['result']:
cases = (result['number'])
print(cases)
```

I added the print(cases) to validate the right data. So now I have an output that looks like this in my console:

```
case_1
case_3
case_2
case_4
case_5
```

I have tried many variations on this theme:

```
with open("cases.txt", "w") as out_file:
for case in cases:
   out_file.write("{}\n".format(case))
```

Most of the time, the only entry I have in the case is case_5. I thought this was to iterate over the list found in cases and then write them to the file.

I also tried to use a variable for the file:

```
myFile = open('cases.txt', 'w')
for element in cases:
    myFile.write(element)
    # myFile.write('\n')
myFile.close
```

I will worry about sorting the list once I can get them into a file. Unless someone has a quick and dirty way of sorting the list prior to the file write?

Comment: @wjandrea Where is the formatting for this so I can do this in the future?

Comment: When you're writing or [edit]ing a post, there's a row of formatting buttons across the top. For code formatting, you can click `{}` or press Ctrl+K. For more, see the [Markdown help](/editing-help).

Comment: Thanks as did not realize that output would be considered code. Will work that in next time!

Comment: Ah yeah, it's not technically code, but pre-formatted text, but the syntax highlighting is blank in this case. If you ever need to disable syntax highlighting in the future, see [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274371/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your **cases** variable every time. So, the final value that will be stored in **cases** will be of case_5 i.e. the cases variable will be a tuple containing only case_5. Since you need to write all the cases in the file, I would suggest creating a list of cases and then write that in the file. Following is the implementation:

```
cases = []
for result in developer['result']:
  cases.append(result['number'])

cases = sorted(cases) # sorting your list assuming that you don't need to sort by any key.

with open("cases.txt", "w") as out_file:
  for case in cases:
    out_file.write("{}\n".format(case))
```

Comment: OH yes! Thank you! That has me in a good place!!